# problem using try, throw catch in PHP for error handling

Tags: php

for the first time i came across try, throw catch statement in PHP, and i felt this could be the better way for handling errors as i was quite messing my error handlers with lots of if else statements, however as i am performing CRUD operations on my script i wanted my error handlers to perform two task.

1. display the user readable or
   custom error message back to the
   user.
2. catch all the error in a file for
   me to read.

i am using the following code..

```
try
{
    $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if($cname == $name)
    {
        throw new Exception('Sorry, Please Change the value to update ');
    }
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE countries SET name = :name WHERE id = :cid");
    $sth->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $sth->bindParam(':cid', $cid);
    $sth->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents("resources/logs/Connection-log.txt", DATE.PHP_EOL.$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

if the condition $cname == $name is true i just want to display the error 'Sorry, Please Change the value to update, however this is not happening here, instead it throws the Fatal Error with this message.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Sorry, Please Change the value to update ' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kokaris/administrator/resources/library/models/countries.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kokaris/administrator/location-manager.php(43): include() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kokaris/administrator/resources/library/models/countries.php on line 24
```

how do i achieve this?

thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your catch is catching a `PDOException` :

```
catch(PDOException $e)
```

While you are throwing a `Exception` :

```
throw new Exception('Sorry, P...
```

`PDOException` is a sub-class of `Exception`, which means that :

- A `PDOException` is an `Exception`
- But an `Exception` is not a `PDOException`.

So, when you are trying to catch a `PDOException`, your `catch` will not also catch `Exception`.

If you want your `Exception` to be catched, you must use something like this :

```
try {

} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
  // deal with PDOException
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  // deal with all other kinds of exceptions
}
```

In this case, the `catch` `PDOException` can be avoided, if you do not want to do some special treatment for `PDOException`s, and just want all exceptions to be dealt with the same way :

```
try {

} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  // deal with all kinds of exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing an `Exception` but catching a `PDOException`.

You should catch the same as you throw, so you might want to change your catch to:

```
catch(Exception $e)
```

Or if you also want to catch that `PDOException` and not do the `file_put_contents` for your own excpetion, add a `catch` for your specific `Exception`.

YOu could ofcourse also change your throw to `PDOException`, same thing basically.